# Putting a check/czech accent on a letter

Tags: accents, diacritical-mark

In mathematical equations, in Latex, how do I put a check/czech accent on a letter?

Comment: `\check{.....}`

Comment: Do you mean `caron`, also known as `haček`? Then write `\v{c}` to get ` č`. Or if you are using an engine and fonts with Unicode support, you may simply paste `č` from a character map.